# EJS Lint Object Return Value

Tags: javascript, ejs

I was trying to look for syntax errors in an EJS template when, I found ejs-lint module at the npm repository. I am trying to use it to identify syntax errors in my template code. The npm documentation for the module https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejs-lint (below in the API section the usage is shown). I am trying to run my scripts through this. The code for the linting script:

```
/*
 *  For checking ejs scripts
 */
const ejs = require('ejs');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const syntax_checker = require('syntax-error');
const ejslint = require('ejs-lint');

function _template_loader (name){
  /*
    loads a template and passs it to the given callback
  */
  return fs.readFileSync(__dirname+'/views/'+name+'.html', 'utf-8');
}
const _filename = 'index';
(function(){
    // main checker
    let mainnav_opts = {
     langoptions: [
        {
          href: '#',
          langcode: 'en',
          langname: 'English',

        },
     ]
    };
    let jumbo_opts = {
        renderParticlesNum : 10
    };
    let index_opts = {
      langoptions: [
        {
          href: '#',
          langcode: 'en',
          langname: 'English',

        },
        ],
        renderParticlesNum: 10,
    };

    let index_parsed = ejslint(_template_loader(_filename), index_opts);
    let jumbo_parsed = ejslint(_template_loader(_filename), jumbo_opts); 
    let mainnav_parsed = ejslint(_template_loader(_filename), mainnav_opts);

    console.log('Index: '+ (!index_parsed ? 'Passed' : 'Failed'));
    console.log('Mainnavbar: '+ (!mainnav_parsed ? 'Passed' : 'Failed'));
    console.log('Jumbotron: '+ (!jumbo_parsed ? 'Passed' : 'Failed'));
})();
```

As per the documentation, the ejslint function should return a node-syntax-error object (from syntax-error module). However, I am only getting undefined. Does this mean there are no syntax errors (I am still getting some errors in the page)?

Edit: To make this better, I am including an ejs partial which, I think is causing the errors:

```
<div id='indexjumbtrn' class='jumbotron'>
    <div id='jumbo-bg-container'>
      <!--
        @ ejs : server sends the number of particles to create and render based on
                some initial client heuristics
      -->
      <% var anim_win_width = document.getElementById('jumbo-bg-container').style.width; %>
      <% var anim_win_height = document.getElementById('jumbo-bg-container').style.height; %>
      <% function fillpart(){ %>
        <% /* fills a particle color randomly */ %>
        <% var r = parseInt(Math.floor(Math.random()*255+1)); %>
        <% var g = parseInt(Math.floor(Math.random()*255+1)); %>
        <% var b = parseInt(Math.floor(Math.random()*255+1)); %>
        <% var a = parseFloat((Math.random()*(0.89-0.73)) + (0.73)).toPrecision(2); %>
        <% return 'rgba(' + r + ',' + g + ',' + b + ',' + a +')'; %>
      <% } %>
      <% function randpos(mn, mx){ %>
        <% return ((Math.random()*(mx-mn))+mn); %>
      <% } %>
      <object id='svgobj'>
        <svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11' viewBox='0 0 450 450' id='dotbox'
          width=<%= anim_win_width+'px' %> height=<%= anim_win_height+'px' %>>
        <% if(renderParticlesNum !== undefined){ %>
          <% var parts = renderParticlesNum; %>
          <% parts.forEach(function(p){ %>
            <% var fillv = ''+fillpart(); %>
            <% var cx = parseInt(randpos(0, anim_win_width)); %>
            <% var cy = parseInt(randpos(0, anim_win_height)); %>
            <% var r = parseInt(randpos(10, 16)); %>
            <% var partid = 'part-'+r(0, 120); %>
            <g style='margin:5% 5% 5% 5%;' fill='white' width=24 height=24 id=<%= partid %>> >
              <circle class='particle' fill=<%= fillv %> cx=<%= cx %>
                cy=<%= cy %> r=<%= r %>></circle>
            </g>
          <% }); %>
        <% } %>
        </svg>
      </object>
    </div>
    <div id='create-form' class='container'>
      <h2 id='jumbotag'>Tag goes here</h2>
      <p><a class='btn btn-primary' id='jumbobtn' href=<%= jumbolink %>>Try Now</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: *"Does this mean there are no syntax errors (I am still getting some errors in the page)?"* - What errors are you getting? From a quick read through I don't see any *syntax* errors.

Comment: Hi, the errors are actually in the ejs template code, not this snippet here. 
And, the other error that is still persisting is a TypeError (which if I am right is because, I am missing a value in the render context object that was passed to the template).
So, to clarify, does the return value of undefined from ejslint function mean there are no errors in the template code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having a similar issue just now, and I believe the `undefined` return value is expected when no linting errors are found.

As you said, `ejs-lint` depends on `syntax-error` for error checking. The [documentation for `syntax-error`](https://github.com/browserify/syntax-error) states:

> If `src` has a syntax error, return an error object `err` that can be printed or stringified.
>
> If there are no syntax errors in `src`, return `undefined`.

Similar, you should get an error object if you throw a syntax error into your EJS file on purpose as a sanity check. You can also use the `ejslint` CLI command to manually check a file.

I get `undefined` when I test the code partial you posted.